# html form response show on same Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, response

I've a simple form that I'm trying submit and get the response and show it in Page. When page loads up first I'm trying to get hidden fields initialized next making an Ajax call when form is submitted. Due to some reason it's not working. Can you please review this code and let me know where I'm making mistake ?

**HTML (From):**

```
<form id='the-form' onsubmit="return submitForm();" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" size="45" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" />
    <input type="hidden" name="mem" id="mem" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="mac" id="mac" />
    <input type="hidden" name="mkn" id="mkn" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="mki" id="mki" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    <br />
    <div class="form_result"></div>
</form>
```

**Java Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('Onload');
    var ownerEmail = window.localStorage.getItem("Email");
    // alert(ownerEmail);
    var actCode = window.localStorage.getItem("ActivationCode");
    document.getElementById("mem").value = ownerEmail;
    document.getElementById("mac").value = actCode;
    document.getElementById("mkn").value = "ownerMaster";
    document.getElementById("mki").value = "27";

    function submitForm() {
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST', 
            url: 'http://dev.mywaggintales.com/pets/media2s3.php', 
            data:$('#the-form').serialize(), 
            success: function(response) {
                var resultObject = JSON.parse(response);
                if (resultObject.wtSuccess) {
                    alert('Success');
                    // If Successful Store 
                    var addressID = resultObject.wtSuccess[1].wtPayload.wtAddressID;
                } else {
                    alert('Failed');
                    // Code Change and Parse the JASOn Object and show it in UI
             }
        }});
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Where is default action of `<form>` submission prevented?

Comment: Why assume it's anywhere? I believe that's exactly the issue at hand. OP, as a nitpick, you're also missing a closing quote for your `onsubmit="...`, though I assume the browser would clean this up for you.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Is actcode define?? Please use document.ready and put your code inside the function may be it's missing that scope

Answer (score 0):

You have to prevent default submit action

```
function submitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   ...
}
```

Comment: That doesn't make any difference. I added and tested now.

Comment: You can try also add return false; into end of this callback function

Comment: Also you have syntax error here - onsubmit="return submitForm();
You missed closing quote - "

Comment: @ParthaMitra <form id='the-form' onsubmit="return submitForm();" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Answer (score -1):

```
 $('.submit-button').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = 'page action';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: {
            field1: $("input[name=field1]").val(),
            field2: $("input[name=field2]").val()
        },
        success: function (data)
        {
            alert(data);
        }
    });

});
```

You can prevent to reload page using this code